# JavaScript lose focus

Tags: javascript

I have a `div` that is set to `display:inline` using the `onclick()` JS event handler.  How do I make the `div` go back to `display:none` when I click any where else on the page other than the now visible div?

I've Googled about `blur` and setting the `focus` to another element but I don't know how to actually do it.

Answer (score 2):

*If you want to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com), it is easy:*

```
$('*').click(function(){
  if ($(this).attr('id') !== 'div_id'){
     $('#div_id').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

The above becomes rather slow with **all * selector**, So I would recommend you to use [jQuery Outside Events plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/).

**Example:**

```
$('#div_id').bind('clickoutside', function(){
  $(this).css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: I don't really want to use jQuery, but I didn't specify so you win.

Comment: @Roboju: Then I hope you find a solution in vanilla javascript soon :)

Answer (score 0):

you can create an absolute div covering the whole window area by giving it 100% width and height and then give it an onclick to display:none your div. your div should have a z-index greater than the absolute div

Answer (score 0):

the raw js sample can be find [here](http://wgcdesigns.wordpress.com/2007/11/23/hide-show-div-onclick-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e) var e = window.event;
  if (e.target.id == 'the_id_of_your_div') {
    // Do something
  } else {
    // Do something else
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the html look like that uses this?

Comment: <div id='the_id_of_your_div'>
Some text
</div>

The event will fire whenever there is a click anywhere on the page